# How to make in-stream ads show in youtube JavaScript iframe player

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have an embedded youtube iframe player in my html to play some youtube video, but I found that there are no in-stream ads when playing the video with my iframe player, no matter pre-roll or mid-roll, and those youtube videos will show ads when playing on youtube app or youtube website.

Can somebody help figure out the reason or tell me how to make the in-stream ads show in youtube iframe player?

thanks

Comment: Same here, can't show any in-stream ads in my iframe YouTube player, any help?